# Angular translate: Variable replacement with filtering by date

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

how can I apply filter to the dynamic translate variable? I use something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
{{'REGISTER_PAGE_USER.BIRTHDAY_MIN_DATE'
   | translate:'{ minimum: (minDate | date:'MMMM dd yyyy') }'}}
```

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the filter in the controller like so:

```
$scope.minDate = $filter('date')(minDate, 'MMMM dd yyyy');
```

This way you don't have to do it in your template.

Date documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).